# How to create an action for a UITabBarItem?

Tags: iphone

I have created a UITabBar and UITabBarItems without UITabBarController on it, now i want to know how to place an action on click of the UITabBarItem.What is the method i should use for action on UITabBarItem?

Comment: According to the Human Interface Guidelines, tab bars are for switching views. Are you sure you don't want to use a tool bar?

Answer (score 23):

You can't set an action on a `UITabBarItem` object directly. Instead, your view controller should implement the following `UITabBarDelegate` method:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item;
```

This method is called when the user selects a tab (i.e. `UITabBarItem`).

Comment: this worked for me but remember to set the tabbar's delegate to 'self' in viewdidload()

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a UINavigationController? If so, from the active view controller subclass you get the navigationItem and add the buttons to it, e.g.:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;
{
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];
    UIBarButtonItem * leftButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Don't Show Again" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: self action: @selector(permanentlyCloseWelcomeView)] autorelease];
    [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem: leftButtonItem];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you get away with using instances of UIToolbar and UIBarButtonItem instead? It could be more straightforward.

```
toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
newPlayerItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"+"
                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                    target:self
                                    action:@selector(newPlayer:)];

NSArray *toolBarItemsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:newPlayerItem, nil];
[toolBar setItems:toolBarItemsArray];
[toolBarItemsArray release];
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a better method than didSelectItem:
for each TabBarItem you create an action:


`[item1 setAction:@selector(pressItem1:)];

[item2 setAction:@selector(pressItem2:)];

[item3 setAction:@selector(pressItem3:)];

[item4 setAction:@selector(pressItem4:)];`


and then you can use the new actions:

```
-(void)pressItem1:(UITabBarItem *) item1 {<br/>
    // Here comes your code which<br/>
    // occurs after pressing item1.<br/>
}
```

That works for me

Comment: you're using a private API. Apple won't approve it

Comment: Seems like yes. Ita an private API.