# UITabBarItem - How to detect a tap/click?

Tags: ios, iphone

In my RootViewController I have a UITabBar with three UITabBarItems. I want to load a separate View Controller when each UITabBarItem is clicked. But I'm not sure how to detect that tap on the bar item.

Previously I just had UIButtons and when clicked executed the code below:

```
[self presentModalViewController:infoViewController animated:YES];
```

Regards,
Stephen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an action for a UITabBarItem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513353/how-to-create-an-action-for-a-uitabbaritem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution in the following thread:

[How to create an action for a UITabBarItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513353/how-to-create-an-action-for-a-uitabbaritem)